# IE9 DIV background image does not resize

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I found that the following CSS instruction does not resize the DIV background image showing in IE9. Do you have any idea?

HTML:

```
<DIV id=window20 class="window smallWindow">
    <STRONG>abcde</STRONG>
    <BR /><BR />
</DIV>
```

CSS:

```
.window {
    Z-INDEX: 20;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #346789 2px dotted;
    POSITION: absolute;
    BORDER-LEFT: #346789 2px dotted;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0.5em;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0.5em;
    WIDTH: 14em;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0.5em;
    FONT-FAMILY: helvetica;
    HEIGHT: 4em;
    COLOR: white;
    FONT-SIZE: 1.0em;
    BORDER-TOP: #346789 2px dotted;
    BORDER-RIGHT: #346789 2px dotted;
    PADDING-TOP: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.6em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.6em
}
.smallWindow1 {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #558822
}
#window20 {
    TOP: 10em;
    LEFT: 8em;
    WIDTH: 8em;
    HEIGHT: 4em;
    background-image :url(../image/interface_system.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: content-box;
}
```

Comment: saw in edit mode that your html code isnt properly formatted, but an edit was suggested before i could make this change

Comment: You have `smallWindow` in your HTML, but `smallWindow1` in your CSS. Is that intentional? Also, all the uppercase is not really an error (both HTML and CSS are mostly case-insensitive), but really nobody else does that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

CSS

```
#window20 {
    TOP: 10em;
    LEFT: 8em;
    WIDTH: 8em;
    HEIGHT: 4em;
    background-image :url(../image/interface_system.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-origin: content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE9 does support `background-size`, but the problem in your example is that you have `background-size: auto`, which means not to stretch the background! (Which is the default if you don't specify the property.)

Solution: use `100% 100%` or `cover` or `contain`, depending on your needs.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

I would have made a fiddle, but I don't have your background picture, and besides, the div in your example doesn't move, so it would not have been very illustrative.